# How to open file which is stored under Miscellaneous folder of a SSIS package from a Script Task?

Tags: ssis, ssis-2005

I added solution related miscellaneous files into the SSIS package under the Miscellaneous folder, e.g. XML, Excel files. I need to open and read those misc. files in a SSIS Script Task, but I can't find the way either to read or getting the path of the misc. files.
I'm using SSIS 2005 in the environment. Please kindly advise.

Thanks!
William Choi

Answer (score -2, accepted):

To get the path to the files, you can open the Properties window while the file under Miscellaneous is selected.  This will show the Full Path and the File Name.

Comment: Thanks, but I'd like to find out the "relative" way.

Comment: This is an answer to the question. Having the full path does not help.

Comment: full path will not help when we deploy project .